# MSSQL Script DB with data - Hebrew fonts replaced with question marks '?'

Tags: sql, sql-server, export

I am trying to script DB with data in order to move DB from MSSQL 2012 to MSSQL 2008R2. All is going very well except that after inserting, Hebrew fonts in data are replaced with question marks. In the script file the Hebrew fonts appears correctly. All INSERT statements contains 'N' before Hebrew strings.
The script file contains large number of rows, therefore the solution cannot involve fixing any row...

Comment: check target columns collation. It should be one of the 4 hebrew collations but probably isn't. (`Hebrew_CI_AS`, `Hebrew_CS_AS`, `Hebrew_CI_AI`, `Hebrew_CS_AI`).

Comment: How do you check, that these characters are broken? Besides the collation (mentioned by @ZoharPeled already), you should ensure, that it's not an issue of your way to display the values...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thank you, adding `COLLATE Hebrew_CI_AS;` worked as magic.